# hive: join with regex

Tags: hive

I'd like to implement a join with regex/rlike condition. But Hive doesn't do inequality joins

```
select a.col_1, b.col_2 
from table1 a left join table2 b
on a.col_1 rlike b.col_2
```

This actually works, but I want to match the full text in b.col2 to a string in a.col_1. Is there a way to do this ?

example dataset:

```
**table1**
apple iphone 
apple iphone 6s
google nexus
samsung galaxy tab

**table2**
apple
google
nexus

**outcome**
col1                   col2
apple iphone          apple
apple iphone 6s       apple
google nexus          google
samsung galaxy tab    null
```

Comment: Is there any logic by which you isolate the string of interest in `col1` using string operations?  Some sample data would be helpful here.

Comment: There isn't unfortunately. I am dealing with search keywords. So I want to match the brand 'apple' in table2 to a keyword 'apple iphone 6s' in table1. To put it in another way, I want to find how many keywords in table2 [full text] match with those in table1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added sample data set

Comment: Is a search keyword always a single word?

Comment: Do you have an ID column for table1?

Comment: Are the values on table1/table2 unique?

Comment: no its not always a single word but they are unique

Comment: Please update your data sample accordingly (and what about an ID column (for both tables)?)

Comment: Shouldn't we have col1:`google nexus` col2:`nexus` in the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  col1
       ,col2

from   (select  t1.col1
               ,t2.col2
               ,count      (col2) over (partition by col1)      as count_col2
               ,row_number ()     over (partition by col1,col2) as rn

        from                   (select  *

                                from    table1 t1 
                                        lateral view explode(split(col1,'\\s+')) e as token
                                ) t1

                left join      (select  *

                                from    table2 t2
                                        lateral view explode(split(col2,'\\s+')) e as token
                                ) t2


                on              t2.token = 
                                t1.token     
        ) t  

where   (   count_col2 = 0
        or  col1 rlike concat ('\\b',col2,'\\b')
        )

    and rn = 1
;
```

---

```
+--------------------+--------+
|        col1        |  col2  |
+--------------------+--------+
| apple iphone       | apple  |
| apple iphone 6s    | apple  |
| google nexus       | google |
| google nexus       | nexus  |
| samsung galaxy tab | (null) |
+--------------------+--------+
```